# What happened at the end of Shot Caller?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, shot-caller

In the movie Shot Caller (2017), in one of the ending scenes, Money kills The Beast, but before he unlockes his own handcuffs. He uses a key but I do not get when he got it. I think that it is related with a previous scene in which he buys matches, an inhaler, razors and another item that I can not recognize.

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia [Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_Caller_(film)#Plot_summary) section on Shot Caller (2017):

> ...as Harlon is about to be taken away by the corrupt correctional officer, he removes a handcuff key and a razor blade that he had smuggled in through his anus