# Why did Money act like that at the end of Shot Caller?

Tags: plot-explanation, shot-caller

I don't understand why Money didn't simply tell the Beast after he was asked "How could have Shotgun inform the police when he was already dead at 5 PM and Herman sent the coordinates only 1 hour before.." that the police took Shotgun's phone and that is how they knew when and where the thing is going down? Why did he bother to frame Shotgun if afterwards he didn't use it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

His intention just wasn't to come out of this clean in the eyes of the Beast, his intention was killing the Beast for threatening his family and taking his place. **There wasn't really a point in trying to convince the Beast that he didn't have anything to do with the cops busting the deal**, nor would it have been of much use in such a mistrust-driven environment.

Afterall, it wouldn't have been all too convincing anyway. It **would still have been stupid of him not to take Shotguns's phone. Even more so, had he not taken it, how would *he* have known about the deal's location?** So why make bad excuses for saving your skin when 5 seconds later you are going to throw it all into a fight to the death with the Beast? And this was *always* the plan, which is [why he smuggled the handcuff key and the kife in](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82545/49) to begin with.

He didn't actually "frame" anything on Shotgun, who definitely was a snitch and would have busted the deal. Money didn't really have to set up anything for that. What he *did* set up was for the cops to find *his* phone so that Money would have a chance to bust the deal himself. But **he didn't really do anything special to frame Shotgun for it**. All he needed was to get to the Beast and once that was done, there was no point in hiding intentions anymore.